# Increase the maximum fingerprint trials of Windows 10 Hello log-in?

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, windows-hello

Currently if Windows does not recognise my fingerprint 3 times, fingerprint gets disabled and PIN becomes required.

Fingerprint sensor normally works well, but when my finger is wet (after washing my hands), it usually fails to recognise my fingerprint. 3 times is too small.Can I increase the number of allowed trials, for example to 10 times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Can I increase the number of allowed trials, for example to 10 times?

According to the following source this is not possible:

> No, you can not set this number of attempts in Windows 10. The fingerprint recognition is a part of the Windows Hello sign in options and has been hard coded into the loginui.exe process, while it is more convenient and more secure than typing a traditional passwords. For security, it is not possible to change the block settings in Windows Hello.

Source [Increase number of fail attempts for fingerprint in Windows 10](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2016/06/increase-number-of-fail-attempts-for-fingerprint-in-windows-10.html)